# 'equals()' between objects of inconvertible types 'EditText' and 'String'

Tags: android

I'm creating a registration page.
 I'm getting an error on `if (!(password.equals(user_conform)))`as "'equals()' between objects of in-convertible types 'Edit Text' and 'String'". I've spent too much time on it to resolve but can't overcome this problem.

Here is my code

```
 EditText name,email,password,conPassword;
        Button register;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;

        String URL="http://192.168.1.8/Register/user.php" ;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

            name=findViewById(R.id.name);
            email=findViewById(R.id.email);
            password=findViewById(R.id.password);
            conPassword=findViewById(R.id.c_password);
            builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
            register=findViewById(R.id.register);

            register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final String user_name=name.getText().toString();
                    final String user_email=email.getText().toString();
                    final String user_password=password.getText().toString();
                    String user_conform=conPassword.getText().toString();

                    if (user_name.equals("")||user_email.equals("")||user_password.equals("")||user_conform.equals("")){
                        builder.setTitle("Something Went Wrong...");
                        builder.setMessage("Please fill all the fields...");
                        displayAlert("input_error");
                    }

                    else {

                        if (!(password.equals(user_conform))){
                            builder.setTitle("Something Went Wrong...");
                            builder.setMessage("Your Passwords are not matching...");
                            displayAlert("input_error");
                        }

                        else {

                            StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                                            try {
                                                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                                                JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                                                String code=jsonObject.getString("code");
                                                String message=jsonObject.getString("message");
                                                builder.setTitle("Server Response...");
                                                builder.setMessage(message);
                                                displayAlert(code);

                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                }
                            }){

                                @Override
                                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                                    Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
                                    params.put("name",user_name);
                                    params.put("email",user_email);
                                    params.put("password",user_password);
                                    return params;
                                }
                            };

                            MySingleton.getInstance(Register.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void displayAlert(final String code){
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    if (code.equals("input_error")){

                        password.setText("");
                        conPassword.setText("");
                    }
                    else {
                        if (code.equals("reg_success")){
                            finish();
                        }
                        else {
                            if (code.equals("reg_failed")){
                                name.setText("");
                                email.setText("");
                                password.setText("");
                                conPassword.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alertDialog=builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the text in the editText when you get the error?

Comment: @elyarabad thanks man but i got solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EditText` is a view object. You'd want to change `if (!(password.equals(user_conform)))` to `password.getText().toString()` to turn it into a string. Essentially, your if statement should look like this: `if (!(password.getText().toString().equals(user_conform)))`.

However, you already have a variable for this, so you can just do this: `if (!(user_password.equals(user_conform)))`

Comment: after this user did not register

Comment: @MansurAsif what happens exactly? this sounds like another problem in your code that you're running into now.

Comment: I'm getting this error now org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

You've mistaken the variables. Replacing `if(!(password.equals(user_conform)))` with `if(!(user_password.equals(user_conform)))` should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks I got the solution